# Launch Desktop PWA in fullscreen/kiosk mode

Tags: windows, vue.js, progressive-web-apps, desktop

I've been searching for a solution, but haven't found anything that works.  I'm attempting to launch a PWA from a Windows Desktop computer added with Chrome in kiosk mode, or at the very least, fullscreen (no menu bars at all).  I would think this would be very common, but I have not found anything that works.  I've added display: fullscreen to the manifest.json, but that does not seem to work for Desktop.

I am fine with any kind of Javascript, but I would like to not require any user interaction to press F11 or anything.  It is intended to be a standalone TV display.

**Actual result after launch:**
[image]

**Desired result after launch:**
[image]

```
{
  "name": "vuejs-display-new",
  "short_name": "vuejs-display-new",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "./img/icons/android-chrome-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "./img/icons/android-chrome-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "./side/adds",
  "display": "fullscreen",
  "orientation": "landscape",
  "background_color": "#000000",
  "theme_color": "#4DBA87"
}
```

Comment: Did you already installed the PWA on the desktop? Or how do you launch it? If you open Dev tools is the SW properly running?

Comment: Yes, it installs an icon on the desktop of my Windows 10 machine. I updated the original post with a screenshot of how it launches, and a copy of the manifest.json file.  The Dev tools says "Service worker has been registered."

Comment: Can you also post the css and html involved in showing the page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After install PWA you should go to shortcut properties and in destiny field add that code at the end:

```
--fullscreen --kiosk
```

Close chrome completely and open the pwa shortcut

Comment: Hmmm, doesn't seem to work.  So this is in the target of the shortcut in Windows 10?

Comment: Yes, in target field. 
To make this work, you can't have another chrome window open, only the pwa should be open

Comment: That appears to have done the trick!  I think I had Chrome open previously.

Comment: Is the arg `--fullscreen` is necessary ?

Comment: Once more,because it's vital: AFTER DOING THE PROPOSED CHANGE, CLOSE **ALL** CHROME WINDOWS. THEN OPEN THE PWA.

Answer (score 1):

The `display:"fullscreen"` property seems working properly as you do not see any browser address bar or other ui elements.

However it seems some CSS properties might set the content outside the viewport. I would double check that there is no layout property interfering with the page content.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying you don't even see the 3 dots, minimize or close on launch with display:fullscreen?  Or it just doesn't display traditional browser items?

Comment: With Fullscreen, your app content will take the whole device screen. So no menu dots nor other device/browser elements.

Comment: Interesting, I'm unable to reproduce a working solution.  I may try doing an absolute minimal interface with no components, just to see if I can get it to launch properly.

Comment: If you could create a StackBliz (or similar) solution, it would be easier to test it as well

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for a solution for this as well. I've upgraded to Windows 10 Pro and am trying to use the Windows Kiosk mode, but the app doesn't seem to appear in the menu of apps you can set to be your kiosk.

One thing to clarify that I think OP was after as well is that simply being fullscreen doesn't work for public kiosks as there are many ways to unintentionally trigger the window to minimize (even on a touch screen) like swiping on the bottom left hand corner reveals the windows icon.

I've only started looking so I'll report back here if/when I find out how to get my app to show on the Win 10 Pro kiosk menu!

Comment: In our case, it's less of an issue to be truly "kiosk mode", because it's a TV display for adds and things, so endusers will not interact with it, but I can't get it to launch in Kiosk or true fullscreen.  We're using Linux, so the OS is different as well.

Comment: Just a clarification, our production machines are Linux.  My dev is Windows, but it launches with the menu dots on both when added using Chrome/Chromium.

Comment: Ah, yikes, yeah so that's a whole new set of issues. It looks like I'm just going to resort to using Windows 10 Pro's Kiosk mode that launches a certain user into fullscreen mode. For you I imagine you'll have to use javascript to launch into true fullscreen mode but sometimes there are restrictions on how you can do that (often requires user interaction to trigger it, so people don't build horrible apps that auto-launch into fullscreen.